# Can WF4 promoted properties be queried directly through the InstanceStore?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Further to my previous question [Resuming a persisted Window Workflow 4 Activity without knowing concrete type of activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349088/resuming-a-persisted-window-workflow-4-activity-without-knowing-concrete-type-of)

Is there a way of querying promoted properties directly through the `InstanceStore` (in my case a [SqlWorkflowInstanceStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.durableinstancing.sqlworkflowinstancestore.aspx) instance), given a workflowId?

I can query the database directly with SQL, but wondered if this could be done directly through the instance store which I already use in my code. I've been looking at the [SqlWorkflowInstanceStore.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.durableinstancing.instancestore.execute.aspx) method and the [QueryActivatableWorkflowsCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.durableinstancing.instancestore.execute.aspx) but can't see that these do quite what I want.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use SQL commands to query promoted properties.

Comment: Thanks @Maurice - I suspected it was so. I feel like I am missing something here though and may be trying to solve a more complex problem than I need to. The root issue (linked question) is that I want to resume a previously persisted workflow, where I may not know the concrete type when I come to resume (although the type will def. be available in bin folder), without examining the persisted workflow first. I'm jumping through hoops like this question to try and save and retrieve the type data but wonder if I've missed the point. Is there a simpler way, or is this route correct?

Comment: If there are a few workflow definitions I tend to create multiple database. Otherwise I keep track of the WF instance ID and the WF definition is a separate app specific table by inserting a new record when I start a workflow.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me this way : used a persistance participant to store the activity type and then used the instance view to retrieve this type.

```
InstanceHandle handle = instanceStore.CreateInstanceHandle(instanceId);
InstanceView view = instanceStore.Execute(handle, new LoadWorkflowCommand(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
string activityType = view.InstanceData[MyParticipantExtension.GetActivityTypeXName()].Value as string;
```